# Google Oauth login using python

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager python client library.
when i try to create token through command prompt it's asking to accept the account permissions. 
but the button was disabled. i can't able to submit the account permissions.

Comment: please post relevant code, or at least steps to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are much more likely to get an answer if you post the code that you are trying to run, and other information. Given what information you have in the question, all I can say is "read the manual".

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/devguide

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/authorization

Good luck!